# ASP.NET MVC linq-to-entities DateTime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I am having four fields in my LOGIN table , they are userid,username,password,datetime...

In date time field, I set default value to Getdate() ... Now i want to retrive recently registered members to last ...

I mean ,

ex..

```
uid    ...     datetime

1               1/21/2011 12:40:12 PM

2               1/23/2011 6:40:12 PM

3               1/24/2011 3:40:12 PM

4               1/24/2011 5:40:12 PM
```

I need to retrive values as ...

```
uid    ...     datetime

4               1/24/2011 5:40:12 PM

3               1/24/2011 3:40:12 PM

2               1/23/2011 6:40:12 PM

1               1/21/2011 12:40:12 PM
```

How to do this using LINQ query ???
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you all the users that have logged in in the last 3 day:

```
(
  from l in Logins
  where
    l.datetime >= System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DateAdd("day", -3, DateTime.Now)
  select l
).OrderByDescending(l => l.Data);
```

If you only want the last 10 users that have logged in, for instance, try this:

```
(
  from l in Logins
  select l
).OrderByDescending(l => l.Data).Take(10);
```